# Multiple CSS Styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I am trying to format information that is being fed to my function. The way I want it is with each item on its own line. The company name is in Eurostile Bold 14pt, the street addresses in Myriad Pro Regular 10pt, and the contact name,phone, and email in Myriad Pro Black 10pt. My attempt so far creates a div with each item being a p tag. I have not found any success in styling the p tags as I would like. Also, I would like to have all the items except for the company name to be indented. When I tried to force the indentation, the output would still be aligned-left. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
addSuggestion = function (company_name, contact_name, street_address_1, street_address_2, phone, email) {
    var output = document.getElementById('container');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var p1 = document.createElement('p');
    var p2 = document.createElement('p');
    var p3 = document.createElement('p');
    var p4 = document.createElement('p');
    var p5 = document.createElement('p');
    var p6 = document.createElement('p');
    div.classList.add('container');

    if(company_name) {
        p1.textContent = company_name;
        div.appendChild(p1);
    }
    else {
        p1.textContent = "*** COMPANY INFO ***";
        div.appendChild(p1);
    }

    if(contact_name) {
        p2.textContent = contact_name;
        div.appendChild(p2);
    }

    if(street_address_1) {
        p3.textContent = street_address_1;
        div.appendChild(p3);
    }

    if(street_address_2) {
        p4.textContent = street_address_2;
        div.appendChild(p4);
    }

    if(phone) {
        p5.textContent = phone;
        div.appendChild(p5);
    }

    if(email) {
        p6.textContent = email;
        div.appendChild(p6);
    }

    output.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: You didn't list any css / styling info in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your `p` tags class names so that you can style them. For example, after creating `p1` you can set its class name:

```
p1.className = "contactname";
```

Then in your stylesheet you can just style using this new class:

```
.contactname {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro Black';
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-indent: 4em;
}
```

Note the `text-indent` property which will indent the first line of each paragraph by a fixed amount. You could also use `padding-left` if this doesn't work for you.

I would also recommend you use more descriptive variable names than `p1`, `p2`, etc. to make it easier to tell which is which for future maintainability.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly! You wouldn't happen to know how to indent, like with a tab, a p tag?

Comment: To indent you could use the `text-indent` property. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Create CSS class for different style. And then add those class to your element dynamically!